# Express.js cannot GET /index.html.var

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, express

So I'm running an express app in a shared hosting (FastComet) but if I want to get to '/' I get this message

> Cannot GET /index.html.var

Apparently it has something to do with the `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way I solved this is adding

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
```

to the `.htaccess`

Answer (score 2):

make sure to include the trailing path like "example.com/app" for sub-domain hosting where in express.js code you would have used @get "/" change it to @get "/app/"

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are good but if you are using shared or cloud hosting for your website and add `directoryIndex:disabled` then the subdomain or other domain may misbehave as the subdomains or addon domain are stored in `public_html/abc.xyz` folder.

The way I solved, you may replace `app.get("/",function(req.res){your code}` to `app.get(["/","/index.html.var"],function(req.res){your code}`

Comment: Interesting approach Ehsan, I'll give it a try.

Comment: This worked for me when using addon domains with a shared hosting c-panel account. Thank you.