# Express router receives GET /index.html.var for index page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hosting

Running an express app on the server receives "GET /index.html.var" for an index page instead of '/'.

```
app.use("/", indexRouter);  //Doesn't work
app.use("/index.html.var", indexRouter);  //Works
```

The same issue persists for robots.txt router too.

```
//Doesn't work
app.get("/robots.txt", function (req, res, next) {
   res.type("text/plain");
   res.send("User-agent: *\nDisallow: ");
});
//works
app.get("/index.html.var/robots.txt", function (req, res, next) {
  res.type("text/plain");
  res.send("User-agent: *\nDisallow: ");
});
```

Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: This isn't express-related. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992349/express-js-cannot-get-index-html-var

Comment: I added it as mentioned but didn't work.

`DirectoryIndex disabled`

I redirected '/index.html.var' to / but that too didn't work.

`RewriteRule ^index\.html\.var$ / [NC,R,L]`